# change accesory type of UITableViewCell when touch on cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //custom code
    [self.table registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    //add table
    ....
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    //a method that add context for cell, return void
    [self cellView:cell withInfo:[self.arrayTaxiList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"cell: %@ -------- indexpath: %d", cell, indexPath.row);
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

the problem is checkmarks are re-appear on another cells when scrolling.
Here's the result from NSLog:

```
cell: <UITableViewCell: 0x16f37a60; frame = (0 0; 320 50); text = ' Hoàng Anh'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x16f33f80>> -------- indexpath: 0
cell: <UITableViewCell: 0x16f37a60; frame = (0 450; 320 50); text = '84'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x16f33f80>> -------- indexpath: 9
cell: <UITableViewCell: 0x16f37a60; frame = (0 900; 320 50); text = 'Ân Thi'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x16f33f80>> -------- indexpath: 18
```

The same problem with cell 1 - 10 - 20 or 2 - 11 - 21 ...

As you can see, the address of cell doesn't changed. That's why the checkmarks re-appear.

How can I get rid of this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: create a `@property` in object of `self.arrayTaxiList` to know the object is checked or not. And check that `@property` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to select accessory type.

Comment: What is the object in `self.arrayTaxiList`? Is it a custom object or a  dictionary?

Comment: `self.arrayTaxiList` contains multiple `NSDictionary`. So, it's possible to do what you said, and I will try it now. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableDictionary *selectionDetails;


-(NSMutableDictionary)selectionDetails{
    if(!_selectionDetails)
        _selectionDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    return _selectionDetails; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    **if([self.selectionDetails objectForKey:@"accessoryType"]){
       NSString *status = [self.selectionDetails objectForKey:@"accessoryType"];
       if([status isEqualToString:@"checked"])
          [self.selectionDetails setObject:@"checked" forKey:@"accessoryType"];
       else
          [self.selectionDetails setObject:@"none" forKey:@"accessoryType"] 
    }else{
        [self.selectionDetails setObject:@"none" forKey:@"accessoryType"]
    }**   
    //a method that add context for cell, return void
    [self cellView:cell withInfo:[self.arrayTaxiList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"cell: %@ -------- indexpath: %d", cell, indexPath.row);
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        **[self.selectionDetails setObject:@"checked" forKey:@"accessoryType"];**
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        **[self.selectionDetails setObject:@"none" forKey:@"accessoryType"];**
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I've found what wrong with my code (my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *taxiDictionary = [self.arrayTaxiList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([[taxiDictionary valueForKey:@"accessoryType"] isEqualToString:@"none"]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    //a method that add context for cell, return void
    [self cellView:cell withInfo:taxiDictionary];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"cell: %@ -------- indexpath: %d", cell, indexPath.row);
    NSMutableDictionary *taxiDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self.arrayTaxiList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        [taxiDictionary setValue:@"checked" forKey:@"accessoryType"];
    } else {
        [taxiDictionary setValue:@"none" forKey:@"accessoryType"]
    }
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I've found what wrong with my code (my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys, the problem which I was described happens because of my stupidity.

It's all happen in this line of code

```
//a method that add context for cell, return void

[self cellView:cell withInfo:[self.arrayTaxiList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

-(void)cellView:(UITableViewCell *)cell withInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {}
```

this method receives an `UITableViewCell` and edits its context. So, that's why the `NSLog` above returns an `UITableViewCell` with the same address in memory.

I changed it to

```
cell = [self cellViewWithInfo:[self.arrayTaxiList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
-(UITableViewCell *)cellViewWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {}
```

and now it works like it should've to.

Thank you guys for replying.